# Debian Xfce session manager does not save desktop app

Tags: debian, xfce

If I select save session through logout within Debian 11.7.0 using xfce4.16, then opened windows like xfce4-terminal, `firefox` and `Thunar` are saved to `~/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-debian:0` but not `Mousepad`. How to tell session-manager to save `Mousepad` in the session as well?

Comment: Is it possible that it's a bug?